# Pycharm does not import dlib

Tags: python, import, pycharm, dlib

I just wanted to install dlib on my Windows 10. I installed cmake and MS Visual 14 2015, which is needed to compile it.
So i opened my Anaconda Enviroment and typed `pip install dlib` it took a while but installed 19.13.1 successfully. I can run 
`python` and then `import dlib` `dlib.__version__` without any problem. It tells me 19.13.1. I can also run `dlib.__file__` and it tells me: `D:\\Programme\\Anaconda3\\envs\\Pytorch\\lib\\site-packages\\dlib.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`

But when i use this enviroment, where dlib seems to work, in Pycharm, i cannot Import it. It just tells me

> ImportError: DLL load failed:....

Anyone a idea why I can't use Pycharm with dlib? Or is there a way to get it to work?

Thanks

Edit:
It is also shown here:
[Project Interpreter Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcx3F.png)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it :

In PyCharm, `Files > Settings > "Project:<nameofyourproject> > Project Interpreter`,
you can see the current Python interpreter used by PyCharm for your project on the top of the window.

If it is not the right one, click on the wheel and `Add...` > Conda Interpreter > click on the box Existing environment and choose it from the list below. If Anaconda is not installed in the default path, your environment will not show up there. So, click on the `...` button to find the path of the python executable of your anaconda environment.
`Path/to/your/anaconda3/env/bin/python`

Once your environment is properly set, you can install dlib directly from PyCharm.
Again, go to `Files > Settings > "Project:<nameofyourproject> > Project Interpreter`. Here, under the path to the interpreter, you can see the list of the installed CONDA packages. On the right of the list there is a button representing a green circle. Deactivate it (click on it) to see all NON-CONDA installed packages. Then, click on the green cross button to add a package. From the new window, type dlib and install it by clicking `Install Package`.

Wait for the installation. Now importing dlib should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pick correct interpreter.
Click `Ctrl+Shift+A`, type "Project interpreter", and choose "Anaconda3" in the drop-down menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my post and added a pic of the Poject Interpreter Settings. I selected the correct one and dlib is showing up in die package list. But i still can't import it. In the site-packages folder is no dlib. Just the dlib-19.13.1.dist-info folder and the dlib.cp36-win_amd64.pyd directly in the site-packages folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you were using MKL library. But I had the same issue caused by MKL.

If you don't set the MKL environment variables after you install you probably get dll error. Here you should do: https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-windows-developer-guide-setting-environment-variables

Just call mklvars intel64 mod ilp64 in "C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries\windows\mkl\bin"

then try python in same shell and import dlib. If it is OK make the variables as system global variables. Variables are PATH, LIB, and INCLUDE.

For tracking: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1287

Answer (score 0):

Before installing the dlib package in pycharm, first you need to download the visual studio community then you get page with some installers there you need to select Desktop development with C++ and install. It will take some time.

Then go to the Pycharm<settings<Python interpreter add the dlib package and install, better to install some old version 19.10.1. We are having issues with some old versions.

It will take some time, but will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Visual Studio to build a python extension on windows.  If you
are getting this error it means you have not installed Visual C++.  Note
that there are many flavors of Visual Studio, like Visual Studio for C#
development.  You need to install Visual Studio for C++.